# Perl diruse not not recognized

Tags: windows, perl, user-interface

my program takes input from the user of a file directory via command line in windows , and then runs diruse on specified path to gather information about disk space available. For some reason the error keeps saying "diruse.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command". Below is a section of my code, to view it in its entirety please go [here](http://pastebin.com/qmtV2gd2). I took the code out of its sub to see if it would work, but it did not.

```
&argument_checking; #calling sub checking user arguements.

#&reading_directory; # reads user given directory.
chdir($user_directory), or die " Directory $user_directory does not exist"; #change to user directory or exit.  
open(DIRUSE, "diruse.exe /* . |"); #opening user given directory path.

foreach my $directory_lines(<DIRUSE>)
{
    chomp $directory_lines;
    push(@directory_lines, $directory_lines); #pushing directory lines from     file into an array
}

close(DIRUSE); #closing

shift(@directory_lines);
shift(@directory_lines);

pop(@directory_lines);

&chop_and_save;
&gui_creator;
```

Comment: Perl 4 needed the `&` in front of functions; Perl 5 doesn't often need them.  You could try using just `diruse` instead of `diruse.exe`, but it probably won't make any difference.  Where is your `diruse.exe` command stored?  Is that location on your PATH?

Comment: I have diruse.exe in my path which for testing purposes is just c:\windows\system32. I also have diruse.exe in the same folder as my script.

Comment: OK; you're out of my realm of expertise, then (though since you `chdir` to a different directory, the `diruse.exe` in the current directory won't be any help.  You should check that the `open()` of the command succeeded: `open(DIRUSE, "diruse /* . |") or die "Failed to open command";` or something similar.

Comment: Does the code you posted give that error? (If so, no idea why you linked to another program that does too.)

Answer (score 0):

That message comes from the command shell, and it means it can't find `diruse.exe` in the current directory or in any directory in that process's PATH.

Comment: The code I posted does give the error, and also I placed diruse.exe in the path I'm using.

Comment: Sorry, got fooled by the stray comma before `or die`.

Comment: As for the path, `cmd` disagrees, and it's the only opinion that counts.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations, I have included diruse in the system32 folder, and am willing to post screen shots. What else could I do to fix this problem?